# Keyval Error with \includegraphics: options undefined

Tags: graphics, document-classes, optional-arguments

I'm trying to make a class file to help me draft bylaws for clubs, but I'm running into a problem with `\includegraphics`.  I want to be able to define a club logo using a `\logo` command (see class file), with the option of passing options to `\includegraphics`, but it doesn't want to work.

Class file:

```
\ProvidesClass{bylaws_min}[2012/10/27 version 0.01 "alpha" Bylaws]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\RequirePackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Sets page margins
\RequirePackage{graphicx}% Allows adding images to documents

\newcommand{\logo}[2][\@empty]{\def\@logoopts{#1}\def\@logoimage{#2}}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
\begin{center}
\ifx\@empty\@logoopts\includegraphics{\@logoimage}\else\includegraphics[\@logoopts]{\@logoimage}\fi
\end{center}%
}
```

Document file:

```
\documentclass{bylaws_min}

\logo[scale=2]{imagefile.jpg}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I've tried both `\logo[scale=2]{imagefile.jpg}` (or some other option other than `scale=2`), or just `\logo{imagefile.jpg}`, and I get variations on this error:

```
Package keyval Error: scale=2 undefined.
See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
 ...

1.7 \maketitle
```

I've played around with this for a while, and it seems that there are two problems.  First, `\ifx` never sees `\@logoopts` as `\@empty` (in other words, the comparison always fails, and the `\else` statement always happens).  Second, if I explicitly create an image like `\includegrahpics[scale=2]{imagefile.jpg}` in `\maketitle`, everything works, but if I try to pass it the options with `\@logoopts` it fails.  But passing it the image file name with `\@logoimage` always works.

Comment: Actually the error message is a bit misleading. As Heiko explains, the contents of the optional argument to `\includegraphics` is not expanded when the command is executed; however the error messages *do* expand things, so you find `scale=2 undefined`. If you mistype an option, for example `\includegraphics[scaled=2]{file}`, you'd get `scaled undefined` and you can see that the part from `=` onward would not appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for `\@empty` as default argument. It only would costs extra work.

```
\newcommand{\logo}[2][]{\def\@logoopts{#1}\def\@logoimage{#2}}
```

The option parser needs explicit key value settings:

```
\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\@logoopts]{\@logoimage}%
```

If I remember correctly, then `\@logoimage` is expanded once by `graphics`. Otherwise
it also would have to be expanded for parsing the file name.

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\includegraphics
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter[\expandafter\@logoopts\expandafter]%
\expandafter{\@logoimage}%
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the options and the image file must be expandable, we can avoid a chain of `\expandafter`.

```
\newcommand{\logo}[2][]{\def\@logoopts{#1}\def\@logoimage{#2}}
% Default setting, in case Ben User calls \maketitle without first calling \logo:
\logo{nofile}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{jpg}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \begin{center}%
    \begingroup
    \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\includegraphics[\@logoopts]{\@logoimage}}\x
  \end{center}%
}
```