# pass to \geometry{} options using a macro - keyval error

Tags: geometry, braces, key-value

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newcommand{\GeomOpts}{a4paper,vmargin={3cm,3cm}}
\geometry{\GeomOpts}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Because of the braces in \GeomOpts its expansion fails when inserted as parameter to \geometry. I did read [1] and [2] but I didn't find a way to adapt this to my simpler \geometry case.

I did try with \expandafter before \geometry and before its braces. Also I did try with xparse's commands intented to define macros/command without success.

[1] [Keyval Error with \includegraphics: options undefined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79494/keyval-error-with-includegraphics-options-undefined)

[2] [Strip one level of braces for using keyval-value within nested keyval](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15808/strip-one-level-of-braces-for-using-keyval-value-within-nested-keyval)

Comment: You can use the standard trick: `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\geometry{\GeomOpts}}\x`

Comment: Worked! Thanks. Can't be written without defining a new command \x? Why \begingroup and \endgroup in these places?

Comment: The encapsulation is needed to define `\x` local and to use the power `\edef`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need this type of tricks. Options passed to the `\geometry` command are cumulative. So you can simply say

```
\geometry{a4paper,vmargin={3cm,3cm}
```

(which I think is your standard) and then add whatever adjustment you like in another `\geometry` command.

So, saying

```
\geometry{a4paper,vmargin={3cm,3cm}
\geometry{headheight=14.5pt}
```

is just the same as doing

```
\newcommand{\GeomOpts}{a4paper,vmargin={3cm,3cm}}
\expandafter\geometry\expandafter{\GeomOpts,headheight=14.5pt}
```

which I think was your aim. I don't see how

```
\newcommand{\GeomOpts}{a4paper,vmargin={3cm,3cm}}
\expandafter\geometry\expandafter{\GeomOpts}
```

is clearer than my suggestion above.

Comment: I don't know what happened. I wrote my post because I thought I had tried with exactly this syntax, that was my first guess after keyval error. Now it worked; I don't know what happened before. :-) Thanks egreg and Marco Daniel!