# Inserting macros mixed with static options

Tags: macros, options

I've been trying on and off for a few days to wrap my head around the following. I want to insert options defined in a macro alongside options statically defined into the option list of another macro. I seem to be able to do this provided that my macro is the first "option" in the macro list (similar to that seen in [pass to \geometry{} options using a macro - keyval error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149397/pass-to-geometry-options-using-a-macro-keyval-error)); but if I try to pass it as the second option, it does not work. I'm confused as to why this is.

Example code that show what works:

```
\def\opts{align=left,minimum width=10em}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\expandafter\node\expandafter[\opts,draw=none] at (0,0) {
    Some fancy text.
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
\def\opts{align=left,minimum width=10em}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\expandafter\node\expandafter[draw=none,\opts] at (0,0) {
    Some fancy text.
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

There's obviously a good reason for this; but I just don't get it. I think it probably has something to do with the way \expandafter is working. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: In the second instance, the `\expandafter` only expands the letter "d" of "draw", and never gets as far as `\opts`.

Comment: However, if you wanted to expand it at the end of the options, you could 8^) do it this way: `\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\tmp{draw=none,}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\node\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter[\expandafter\tmp\opts] at (0,0) {Some fancy text.};
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: Okay; so I'd have to define it all in macros, rather than a mixture of both. Is that right? I am also confused about the chains of \expandafter's (which I have seen in other StackExchange posts... and still don't get)... but I'll muddle through. Thanks so much!

Comment: In my explanation, the 1,3,4,6,7 expands operate on `\opts`, which then leaves the 2,5 expands to operate on `\tmp`, so that by the time you get to `\node`, both `\opts` and `\tmp` are expanded.

Comment: Thanks again Steven. I think I get it now. I'll see if I can't reproduce that sequence by hand. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\expandafter` reads the two tokens that follow it, puts the first aside and causes *one* level expansion of the second one; then the first token is evaluated as usual as if the expansion of the second token had been there to begin with.

Thus your

```
\expandafter\node\expandafter[\opts,draw=none]
```

expands `\opts` because the second `\expandafter` is expanded by virtue of the first one. On the contrary,

```
\expandafter\node\expandafter[draw=none,\opts]
```

can't reach `\opts`, because the two tokens after the second `\expandafter` are `[` and `d`. You need a different strategy, as

```
\expandafter\node\expandafter[\expandafter d\expandafter r\expandafter a\expandafter w\expandafter =\expandafter n\expandafter o\expandafter n\expandafter e\expandafter ,\opts]
```

doesn't seem a viable option. `;-)`

What you can do is invoking a “global” one level expansion:

```
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
\noexpand\node[draw=none,\unexpanded\expandafter{\opts}]}\x
```

The temporary macro `\x` will be forgotten as soon as it is expanded because the first token in its expansion is `\endgroup`; `\node` will remain untouched by `\edef` because of `\noexpand`, while `\opts` will be expanded once by `\expandafter` and the resulting token list won't be expanded further because of `\unexpanded`.

Without `\unexpanded\expandafter{\opts}`, but with just `\opts` is dangerous if `\opts` contains macros such as `\bfseries`; in any case you want its *one level* expansion, not the “all the way” one.

Comment: The only problem with `\bfseries` is that it *should* be robust but it isn't, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Manuel It *is* robust, and this is why it can't go in `\edef`. Unfortunately, `\protected\def` wasn't available when LaTeX2e was released.

Comment: @egreg Ah, okey, that's why `\protected@edef` exists.

Answer (score 4):

assuming (as is most likely the case) your options are just plain text and safe in an `\edef` you can do

```
 \edef\tmp{\noexpand\node[draw=none,\opts] at (0,0)}\tmp
```

as `\edef` will expand all the tokens in its argument (`\node` is prevented from expanding so when `\tmp` is expanded its expansion will be

```
\node[draw=none,align=left,minimum width=10em] at (0,0)
```

If `\opts` does have tokens that may not be fully expanded in this way an alternative is

```
\def\tmp{\node[draw=none,}
\expandafter\tmp\opts] at (0,0)
```

Then `\opts` is only expanded once by the `\expandafter` rather than being fully expanded in an `\edef`.

Comment: What about a possible `font=\bfseries` option inside `\opts`?

Comment: @egreg Then the code needs to be more complicated. But I chose to give simple code together with a note of when it is appropriate. Someone can always come along and try to steal the tick with a fully defensive solution:-)  but I'll add a (simpler) version that can cope with that to make you happy:-)