# Set value of \geometry keys from a macro

Tags: geometry, key-value

I am trying to set parameters of the `geometry` package via macros. For example

```
\def\xxx{false}
\geometry{twoside=\xxx}
```

However the above command, nor `\expandafter\geometry{twoside=\xxx}` seem to work; I also tried `\expandafter\geometry\expandafter{twoside=\xxx}` as suggested by [pass to \geometry{} options using a macro - keyval error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149397/pass-to-geometry-options-using-a-macro-keyval-error) . Is there a way to make this work? (Preferably an expl3 way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sequence of `\expandafter`'s only reaches `t`.

There may be better ways, but without further details on your document class and where `\xxx` is set, this can work

```latex
\def\xxx{false} % or true

\expandafter\geometry\expanded{twoside=\xxx}
```

If you don't trust your users to have a recent TeX distribution that supports `\expanded`, you can do

```latex
\def\xxx{false} % or true

\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\geometry{twoside=\xxx}}\x
```

A more generic way could be

```latex
\newcommand{\js@set@geometry@option}[2]{%
  \expandafter\js@set@geometry@option@aux\expandafter{#2}{#1}%
}
\newcommand\js@set@geometry@option@aux[2]{\geometry{#2=#1}}
```

so you can call

```latex
\js@set@geometry@option{twoside}{\xxx}
```

and any other option can be used.

---

For `expl3` keys, you can define a choice key:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse,geometry,lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\selectoptions}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { jason/class } { #1 }
 }

\keys_define:nn { jason/class }
 {
  twoside .choices:nn = { true, false } { \geometry{twoside=#1} },
  twoside .default:n = true,
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\selectoptions{twoside}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\section{Test section}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am actually try to set this from a `l3keys` boolean value. I have `twosided .bool_set:N = \l__twosided`, and I was trying `\gemetry{twoside=\bool_if:nTF \l__twosided {true} {false}}`. Maybe there's a better way to extract the boolean?

Comment: @JasonSiefken Use a choice key

Comment: That's a nice solution :-). Can you have `.choices:nn` and `.set_bool:N`?

Comment: @JasonSiefken You can use any code inside the second part, together with `\geometry{twoside=#1}`, for instance `\bool_gset:Nn \g_jason_twoside_bool { \use:c { c_#1_bool } }`

Comment: @egreg So where does `\expanded` come from?

Comment: @lyl `\expanded` is a primitive in all recent TeX engines

Answer (score 0):

In `\geometry{twoside=\xxx}`, what you need is to expand `\xxx` first, then `\geometry`. In `\expandafter\geometry\expandafter{twoside=\xxx}`, `t` is expanded first, then `\geometry`.

Here is a solution, to use a macro to collect the key-value list, then pass it to `\geometry{...}`.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\geo@options{}

\appto\geo@options{twoside=}
% now \geo@options == "twoside="

\def\xxx{false}
\expandafter\appto\expandafter\geo@options{\xxx}
% now \geo@options == "twoside=false"

\expandafter\geometry\expandafter{\geo@options}
\makeatother
```